Looking for a graphic novel series
I remember a really good graphic novel I came across 8 or so years ago. I can't remember the title, and much of the story is hazy. I do remember the main character and his sister going after their mother after she gets kidnapped. as well as one of them being stung by a scorpion creature and the mc needing to find a living forest whose trees bear the fruit of life and death.
I know this is fantasy and that the forest gets burned down at the end of the novel, as well as this being a book series first. The inciting incident occurs in the house of the mc grand father and the mother begs them not to follow her. I found the novel in my high school library so I don't know when the actual series was published.

Did you read it in English or another language, e.g. French? What was the format - trade paperback like modern comic collections, or book-sized or larger (like European comic albums)? Was it, in fact, a collection of earlier magazine-format books?
